# Values from $node object in Views Contexual Filter

Tags: 7, views

I'd like to create a PHP contexual filter for a view.

This code isn't right, but I want something like this:

```
global $node;
if ($node->type=="ABC") {
return 5880;
}

if ($node->type=="XYZ") {
return 6200;
}
```

How do I access the $node object in a PHP contexual filter?

Also, is there a better way to debug/troubleshoot this? I feel like I'm operating in complete darkness.

Comment: Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the $node object by doing this in the filter:

```
$node = menu_get_object()
```